# Divs being prevented from going side by side

Tags: html

What im doing should be pretty obvious by having a wrapper and inside the wrapper having 2 divs: Left and Right.  Using Float should put them side by side.  However this is not the case.  My right div "Skills"  is being pushed up over my left div "Bio".

My site is conorpendlebury.com.

Unfortunately I can't post a screenshot.

Comment: plz show your  code

Comment: Is there sufficient space for both div to display on the same line ? And did you place the `float: right` BEFORE the `float: left` ?

Comment: check your code too. you have <p/> in there, that's not correct  https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=http%3A%2F%2Fconorpendlebury.com%2Fhome.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, remove the `margin-top` of `<h2 />` element will solve the problem.

Also you'd better switch the position of these two elements: `<div id="Skills" />` and `<div id="Bio" />`. Sometime it causes troubles when right float element is rendered after left float element.

Comment: It still didnt work.  I changed bio to have float right and skills to have float left.  I also removed the margin-top.

Comment: Add `box-sizing: border-box` style to both `div`s. You added an extra `width` there and that's the reason now.